# Why is adding a List<T> also adding to a different List<T>?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I am creating meshes to send through to Unity to be applied to game objects to be rendered. I have a method that is passed an instance of my MeshData class containing (Vertices, a list of vertex indexes to make triangles, and UV coordinates) and merges that with the current instance of MeshData to produce a final merged MeshData containing the Vertices, Triangle Indexes, and UVs of both merged sets to pass as a Mesh object to Unity.

Reasoning being, I'm making a voxel-type game and I am creating a mesh for each individual block and then merging all the block meshes into a 16x16 "chunk" of blocks. This larger mesh is converted to a Unity Mesh object and applied to a GameObject for the chunk.

When this method is run it is currently getting stuck in an infinite loop that seems to be updating this._tris and data._tris at the same time, so as it loops through data._tris it never reaches the end because every time this._tris is added to, it also updates data._tris. This is unintended behaviour and I'm not sure what is causing it to behave that way.

This particular bit of code was working fine earlier and hasn't been modified at all. But when I modified code in another class it started getting stuck in an infinite loop until it hits an Out of Memory Exception. Regardless of what is being passed to Merge() it should never be getting stuck like that.

```
// Class for creating MeshData
public class MeshData
{
    // MeshData objects
    private List<Vector3> _verts = new List<Vector3>();
    private List<int> _tris = new List<int>();
    private List<Vector2> _uvs = new List<Vector2>();

    // MeshData constructor with parameters
    public MeshData(List<Vector3> v, List<int> i, Vector2[] u)
    {
        this._verts = v;
        this._tris = i;
        this._uvs = new List<Vector2>(u);
    }

    // MeshData default constructor
    public MeshData()
    {

    }

    // Merge Mesh Data
    public void Merge(MeshData data)
    {
        // if data is empty, don't do anything
        if(data._verts.Count <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        // if current meshdata is empty, just set it to be the new data set
        if(this._verts.Count <= 0)
        {
            this._verts = data._verts;
            this._tris = data._tris;
            this._uvs = data._uvs;
            return;
        }
        // if neither case above is true, merge the two data sets
        int count = this._verts.Count;
        this._verts.AddRange(data._verts);
        for(int i = 0; i < data._tris.Count; i++)
        {
            this._tris.Add(data._tris[i] + count);
        }
        this._uvs.AddRange(data._uvs);
    }
}
```

The Merge method should be merging the current MeshData (this) with the given MeshData (data) so that the current MeshData (this) contains the elements of both.

In the Merge method at the for loop "for(int i = 0; i < data._tris.Count; i++)"
it is getting into an infinite loop. When I run the debugger in Visual Studio and watch the Locals variable list, everytime this._tris is updated/added to, it also updates/adds to data._tris. So data._tris is constantly getting larger so the for loop never hits the end of it.

Any help with why it is behaving that way and how to avoid that behavior?

Comment: Can you explain why you expect ` this._tris.Add` not to add anything to `this._tris`?

Comment: @JonathonChase I'm merging 2 distinct instances with different data.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov To clarify, when I add something from data._tris, it should be added to this._tris, but not also modify data._tris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you set a `List<T>` equal to another `List<T>` with the `=` operator, you're establishing a reference to the list, not copying the values over:

---

In your example you are first creating a new `List<int>`:

```
private List<int> _tris = new List<int>();
```

But then, in your constructor, you set `_tris` to reference a different list:

```
this._tris = i;
```

The old `new List<int>()`you had is no longer being referenced and will be garbage collected (eventually). This over-write can also happen in your `Merge` method with the line:

```
this._tris = data._tris;
```

---

If you want `this._tris` to *reference* another list (and thus adding to one adds to the other), you use the `=`.  If you instead want to *copy all the values over*, you use `AddRange` like you do with `_verts`:

```
this._tris.AddRange(data._tris);
```

Comment: I just started using c# so I wasn't aware of this type of behavior. These are all great points. So to summarize, if I want to copy the contents of a list onto another list, use AddRange and not "="? Is that right?

Comment: @Ali Correct! This comes down to C#'s differentiation between ["value types" and "reference types."](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)  A `List<T>` is a reference type and therefore "_contains a pointer to another memory location that holds the data._"  When you use the `=` operator, you're making whatever's on the left _reference_ whatever's on the right.  The `AddRange()` method _adds the elements_ contained in one list to the end of the other list.

Answer (score 4):

At first glance I'd say your problem is `this._tris = data._tris;`, you're making `this._tris` point to `data._tris`. Might want to add the contents of `data._tris` to `this._tris` instead.

Comment: If using "=" between two lists only makes a reference and doesn't just copy the contents, what would be the best way to copy the contents without connecting them by reference?

Comment: @Ali As Foggzie explained in more detail `this._tris.AddRange(data._tris);` will add the elements of `data._tris` to `this._tris`. Also, note, that it's not a deep copy if that list holds anything other than primitives. This means that if you have mutable objects in `data._tris` and you add them to `this._tris` and then iterate over `this._tris` and update the state of those objects, those modifications will be reflected in the elements of `data._tris` too for the same reference principle that caused 2 field variables reference the same list object.